# Build app failing saying learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
    Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in 
    modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat- 
    25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
    Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesTask.doTaskAction(CheckDuplicateClassesTask.kt:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat-25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:128)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
    ... 103 more
```

Comment: Have you added android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true in your gradle .properties

Comment: found in modules core-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and support-compat- 25.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0).... it is your problem. try to migrate your project to androix. if you send your gradle file it would be good :)